# How to write CFG for languages

Tags: context-free

How do you write the CFG for the following language:

{a<sup>x</sup> b<sup>y</sup> c a<sup>x+y</sup>}

Is there some formula or rules I need to follow? An explanation will be so appreciated.

What I tried is:

First I broke a<sup>x+y</sup> into a<sup>x</sup>a<sup>y</sup>  which gives:

{a<sup>x</sup> b<sup>y</sup> c a<sup>x</sup>a<sup>y</sup>}

Then

S ---> aSa | B
B ---> bB | c

The problem I am facing now is how to include a<sup>y</sup>.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no  recipe. It is like dancing or riding a bicycle, you learn by practicing. You have to get an intuition for how the CFG can be used. Try to do first the following language: $\{a^xca^x\mid x\geq 1\}$, then $\{a^xcb^x\mid\ldots\}$, then $\{a^xa^yca^xa^y\mid\ldots\}$, then $\{a^xa^yca^{x+y}\mid\ldots\}$. That should put you on track. Also try it with $x\geq 0$ and with $x\geq 1$, and same for $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per advice from others:

Rewrite into $a^xb^yca^ya^x$.

Now it is easy to see the nested structure (or symmetry in the exponent)

So we will have

- $S_1 \rightarrow a S_1 a$ $|$ $S_2$
- $S_2 \rightarrow b S_2 a$ $|$ $c$